# Mysql LEFT JOIN with most recent record?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have this query:

```
SELECT A.ISIN, A.CUSIP, A.Currency,  A.StatedFinalMaturityDate, 
        A.FirstPayDate, A.PaymentDelay, A.trancheName, A.DealTicker,
        B.TrancheCoupon, B.OneMonthCoupon, B.SettleDate, B.Factor, 
        B.paymentDate
from table1 A
    left JOIN table2 B on (A.DealTicker = B.DealTicker AND A.trancheName=B.trancheName)
where A.ISIN IN ('XS2004372095','XS1679333432','XS0333340361',
                'XS0333337813','XS0333324241','XS0333323862',
                'XS0333323516','XS0333323193','XS0333316908',
                'XS0333313988','USWFMW0N9Z05','USWFHZ5XIY05',
                'USWFHVA6TK04','USWFHTXSQJ03');
```

Here table1 have one record correspond to each ISIN but the table2 can have multiple rows.

table2 has settleDate column which show latest row. So I want to select only latest row from table2 only. Since table2 need two JOINING column I m little confused here.

PS: I cannot use mysql 8 features like row_number() as mysql server version is 5.7. And my table contains more than 150millions records. I tried a approaches but didn't work because of huge data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old MySQL version, so you cannot use windows functions but must access the same table twice. You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `MAX` to get the last rows. Here is an example with `MAX`:

```
SELECT 
  a.isin, a.cusip, a.currency,  a.statedfinalmaturitydate, a.firstpaydate,
  a.paymentdelay, a.tranchename, a.dealticker, b.tranchecoupon,
  b.onemonthcoupon, b.settledate, b.factor, b.paymentdate
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE (dealticker, tranchename, settledate) IN
  (
    SELECT dealticker, tranchename, max(settledate)
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY dealticker, tranchename
  )
) b ON b.dealticker = a.dealticker AND b.tranchename = a.tranchename
where a.isin IN ('XS2004372095','XS1679333432','XS0333340361','XS0333337813',
                 'XS0333324241','XS0333323862','XS0333323516','XS0333323193',
                 'XS0333316908','XS0333313988','USWFMW0N9Z05','USWFHZ5XIY05',
                 'USWFHVA6TK04','USWFHTXSQJ03');
```

Comment: I think the left join block will cause performance issue as I have approx 160m rows. records in table2.

Comment: With an index on table2(dealticker, tranchename, settledate) that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT A.ISIN, A.CUSIP, A.Currency,  A.StatedFinalMaturityDate, A.FirstPayDate, A.PaymentDelay, A.trancheName, A.DealTicker,
       B.TrancheCoupon, B.OneMonthCoupon, B.SettleDate, B.Factor, B.paymentDate
FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DealTicker, trancheName ORDER BY settleDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table2 B
     ) B
     ON A.DealTicker = B.DealTicker AND
        A.trancheName = B.trancheName AND
        B.seqnum = 1
WHERE A.ISIN IN ('XS2004372095','XS1679333432','XS0333340361','XS0333337813','XS0333324241','XS0333323862','XS0333323516','XS0333323193','XS0333316908','XS0333313988','USWFMW0N9Z05','USWFHZ5XIY05','USWFHVA6TK04','USWFHTXSQJ03');
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
SELECT A.ISIN, A.CUSIP, A.Currency,  A.StatedFinalMaturityDate, A.FirstPayDate, A.PaymentDelay, A.trancheName, A.DealTicker,
       B.TrancheCoupon, B.OneMonthCoupon, B.SettleDate, B.Factor, B.paymentDate
FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN
     table2 B
     ON A.DealTicker = B.DealTicker AND
        A.trancheName = B.trancheName AND
        B.settleDate = (SELECT MAX(b2.settleDate)
                        FROM table2 b2
                        WHERE b2.DealTicker = B.DealTicker AND
                              b2.trancheName = B.trancheName
                       )
WHERE A.ISIN IN ('XS2004372095','XS1679333432','XS0333340361','XS0333337813','XS0333324241','XS0333323862','XS0333323516','XS0333323193','XS0333316908','XS0333313988','USWFMW0N9Z05','USWFHZ5XIY05','USWFHVA6TK04','USWFHTXSQJ03');
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Thanks for always being the first to resolve my problem.. I also thought about your approach but the problem is mysql database server is running on version 5.7 and ROW_NUMBER() is not supported there.  (PS: I m not sure who is downvoting the answer.)